# Android app and tokbox integration

Tags: android, video-streaming, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to build an POC in an android app where I need to build an peer-to-peer video chat/conference I googled and found out tokbox is good option to start with, so I started referring the tokbox tutorial/docs in their official site,now to some extent I got clarity on how to get an start on Android side but I also need an Java server side implementation for that I referred the server-sdk but I didn't got clarity on how start coding from server even though I referred the server side implementation for tokbox java-sdk given in git.

can any one help me how to kick start on server side implementation and android app to server application interaction,some code snippets and sample project will help me a lot to start off.

In short I need to implement Java server side tokbox api integration.
Android(publisher)----->Server sdk----->Android(subscriber)

Comment: Hi Manideep.  I work for SightCall.  We operate a highlevel video platform-as-a-service - we offer an Android SDK as well and have a starter app on github.  You might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the quick start guide for OpenTok Java SDK here:
https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server/java/

Essentially, you should make a server that returns a sessionid and token string upon getting an endpoint hit, such as somedomain.com/api/session/start. The quick start samples show you how to generate a session id and token for these requests. The server should also take archive requests at an endpoint, say somedomain.com/api/archive/start, which when a proper archive ID is POSTed to, will call the startArchive method of the server object and pass in an archive id.